# In pandas, how to apply a function to every column that returns two columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to apply a function to every column of my grouped multiindex pandas dataframe.

If I had a function `my_function()` that returns a scalar, I would use

```
data_grouped = data.groupby(['type'])
data_transf = data_grouped.apply(lambda x: my_function(x))
```

However, consider another function `my_function_array()` takes an array (all `n` rows within one group) as an input and returns an `n x 2` array as the output.

How can I apply this to every column of my grouped dataframe `data_grouped`? That is, I want to take every column of my grouped data of `m` rows and replace it by the `n x 2` output of `my_function_array()`.

Here's some sample data. There are other groups (types) but I only show one

```
type   frame   x            y           
F1675      1   77.369027    108.013249
           2   107.784096   22.177883
           3   22.385162    65.024619
           4   65.152003    77.74970

def my_function_array(data_vec, D=2, T=2):

    N = len(data_vec) - (D-1)*T # length of embedded signal
    embed_data = np.zeros([N,D])

    for di in range(-D//2,D//2):
        embed_data[:,di] = data_vec[ np.arange((D//2+di)*T, N+(D//2+di)*T) ]         

    return embed_data
```

Appyling the function to the second column `y`

```
my_function_array(np.array([108.013249, 22.177883, 65.024619, 77.74970]))
```

I have

```
array([[ 65.024619, 108.013249],
       [ 77.7497  ,  22.177883]])
```

So, the expected output is

```
    type   frame   x_1          x_2        y_1         y_2
   F1675       1   22.385162    77.369027   65.024619  108.013249
               2   65.152003   107.784096   77.7497     22.177883
```

where `x_1` and `x_2` are the two columns resulting from `x` (the naming is not important, can be anything). Note that the groups have become shorter and wider.

Comment: Is possible add some sample data, sample function and expected output?

Comment: Hi @jezrael , please see my expanded question! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need return `pd.DataFrame`:

```
def my_function_array(data_vec, D=2, T=2):
#    print (data_vec.name)

    N = len(data_vec) - (D-1)*T # length of embedded signal
    embed_data = np.zeros([N,D])

    for di in range(-D//2,D//2):
        embed_data[:,di] = data_vec[ np.arange((D//2+di)*T, N+(D//2+di)*T) ]         
    return pd.DataFrame(embed_data).add_prefix(data_vec.name)


f = lambda x: pd.concat([my_function_array(x[y]) for y in x], axis=1)

data_transf = data.groupby(['type']).apply(f)
print (data_transf)
                x0          x1         y0          y1
type                                                 
F1675 0  22.385162   77.369027  65.024619  108.013249
      1  65.152003  107.784096  77.749700   22.177883
```

Comment: That's very close! How do you apply this to every column of the dataframe?